# How to model the two entity class and two Tables(metadata and actual content) for storing files

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have to store files in db as byte array. So we have decided to create two tables such that **meta data** will go into one table and the **actual content** into a different table. We are using spring jpa. Most of the time, we will query meta data and show tiles in client side. When we need to download actual content, separate query will be fired to second table. Now the Primary key of Metadata is attachment_id which is auto incremented and it is also **PK** and **FK** to the actual content table. Now we need two entities which makes more sense for our context. Now my problem is,

1. How should be the entities look like? Because on persisting meta data, attachment_id will be generated which should be the PK and FK to the actual content's table. How should I persist the actual content into second table. Should I use one entity by embedding **actual data entity** in **meta data entity**?
2. On retrieving the meta data, I don't need to get actual content. Only meta data is enough.
   If I need actual content, I wil do a separate query. How can I get metadata without actual content by not using native query?

Can you guys suggest the best approach to model the entities. I am new to spring JPA. I am planning to use JPARepository to persist the entities. Should I need two separate repositories for both metadata and actual content?

Advanced thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for information about lazy fetching right now, and I stumbled at this
[article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-lazy-load-entity-attributes-using-jpa-and-hibernate/).

It seems that **Fetching subentities** section is your way to go. You can change your db to put meta and content in one table, and then fetch them separately by making use of subentities mapped to this one db table.